# Why do primitive types in C# have their own operations?

Tags: c#, primitive-types

A few days ago, I decided to start learning C#. So, I got a book and started reading and practicing with code. I was surprised when I saw that `string` in C# is considered a primitive type.

But I was more surprised when I saw that `string`, as well as all the other primitive types in C# have methods. I'm a Java developer and my understanding was that primitive data types don't have methods, only classes have. But in C#, the following is valid:

```
string name = "alex";
Console.WriteLine(name.ToUpper());
```

How is this possible? Are they really primitives? What am I missing here?

Comment: Bad example, given that in java String is an object so "abc".toString() works in Java as  does "abc".ToString() in C#  A distinction is that 123.toString() will not work in java, whereas 123.ToString() will work in C#  So you could ask why int (which is a primitive in C# Console.WriteLine(typeof(int).IsPrimitive) //true   has methods.

Comment: You could consider strings to be an "intrinsic" type, if not primitive.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`string` is not a primitive type in C#. It's one of two predefined (i.e., part of the language specification) reference types in C# (the other being `object`). The primitive types in C# are `Boolean` (`bool`), `Byte` (`byte`), `SByte` (`sbyte`), `Int16` (`short`), `UInt16`, `Int32` (`int`), UInt32 (`uint`), `Int64` (`long`), UInt64 (`ulong`), `IntPtr`, `UIntPtr`, `Char` (`char`), `Double` (`double`), and `Single` (`single`).
Note that the specification states "it is also possible to use structs and operator
overloading to implement new “primitive” types in the C# language" but that `typeof(MyStruct).IsPrimitive` is `false` if `MyStruct` is a user-defined `struct`.

> I got a book and started reading and practicing with code. I was surprised when I saw that string in C# is considered a primitive type.

The book said this? Which book?

> I'm a Java developer and my understanding was that primitive data types don't have operations, only classes have.

Plainly and simply, C# and Java are different languages. In C# there is the notion of `object` from which almost everything derives (yes, there are exceptions the most important of which is interfaces). From `object` there is a derived type called `ValueType`. Derivatives of `ValueType` are `struct`s which have value semantics. All other derivatives of `object` are reference types. All of these `object`s encapsulate data and behavior (i.e., they can have methods).

> `string name = "alex";`
>
> `Console.WriteLine(name.ToUpper());`
>
> How is this possible?

I don't understand your confusion with this code snippet. `name` is an instance of `string` that is definitely assigned by the string literal `"alex"` and we are invoking one of the overloads of the method `String.ToUpper` on `name`. Then the overload of `Console.WriteLine` that accepts an instance of `string` is invoked. You can even do this

```
Console.WriteLine("alex".ToUpper());
```

> Are they really primitives?

No. `string` is not a primitive.

> What am I missing here?

That C# and Java are related but very different programming languages.

Comment: You're right, after a little research (and reading all your answers here) I found out that there aren't any primitives in C#. I wasn't confused with the code, I was only confused that you're allowed to perform operations in types like int. For example, int i = 5; i.ToString();

Comment: `ToString` is a `virtual` method defined on the class `object` from which `ValueType` derives from which `Int32` derives (`int` is a reserved keyword in C# that is short for `Int32`). `Int32` provides an `override` of `ToString`.

Comment: +1 Very nice answer.  (By the way, here is a quick verification of your assertion that `String` isn't a primitive type: `typeof(String).IsPrimitive`)

Comment: Worth pointing out that int is a primitive but still in C#, you can say 5.ToString() you cannot do 5.toString() in Java.  Furthermore, in java, you can do "abc".toString() like C# "abc".ToString().   He obviously had no surprise in the idea that a non-primitive can have methods. His surprise was that a primitive in C# can.

Comment: The main difference between C#/Java is C# has a unified type system. **All** types derive from `System.Object`, and as such, can have fields/properties/methods _except_ for types deriving from `System.Enum` (ironically opposite of java which supports enum methods). There's a difference between built-in/keyword types and primitive types. Primitives are value types that that use the keyword for themselves as storage. See [Int64](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/57bfe474518ab5b7cfe6bf7424a79ce3af9d6657/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Int64.cs#L15) use `long` to store value.

Answer (score 17):

`string`, in C#, is a class - it's an alias for [System.String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx).

However, all types in .NET have methods.  It is truly object oriented, and everything derives from System.Object, which also means that the [methods of System.Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object_methods.aspx) work on **every type** in C#.

Comment: How about structs (as `int` aka `Int32` and other value types are structs)? From my understanding they don't support inheritance. Are they still derived from `System.Object`?

Comment: @divo: All `struct` derive from `System.ValueType` which derives from `System.Object` and they are implicitly `sealed` (meaning they can not be derived from).

Comment: Aliasing and Inheritance for posterity: C# string = System.String (class) > System.Object |  C# int = System.Int32 (struct) > System.ValueType > System.Object | It always ends at System.Object. See System.Object methods here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object_members.aspx and see these on any instance or value in your application.

Comment: Be careful! Not everything derives from `System.Object`!

Comment: @Jason: Thanks for the clarification! What does *not* derive from `System.Object` then?

Comment: @divo: Pointer types and interfaces for example.

Comment: It's important to note that value-type storage locations have different semantics from instances of value types.  Although `System.Integer` inherits from `System.Object`, a storage location of type `System.Integer` doesn't actually hold an object of that type--it holds four bytes that together are interpreted as a 32-bit integer value.  Likewise, a storage location of type `System.Drawing.Point` doesn't actually hold an object of that type--it holds four integer fields `X`, `Y`, `Width`, and `Height`.

Comment: @0xA3  Yes funnily enough in C# you can do it to int too. In C# this works.  123.ToString()  But 123.toString() doesn't work in  Java.   Similarly  int a;  and doing a.ToString() or a.toString(). In C# it works in Java you can't. Though indeed int is called primitive in C#  Console.WriteLine(typeof(int).IsPrimitive); So maybe C# defines primitive differently

Answer (score 7):

Short answer is that they're not really primitives. The compiler will switch out your `string` with a `String` object.

Comment: `string` is just a keyword that is an alias for `System.String`.

Comment: @Jason - Isn't that all an alias is? Something that is effectively a place-holder name for some other *real* thing? In other words isn't what you're saying logically the same as saying the compiler switches `string` to `System.String`? Now I'm not sure if it happens when compiling to CIL or when the CIL is JIT'd at runtime, but at some point a `string` **is** a `System.String` right?

Comment: I guess I just misunderstood what you meant by "the compiler with switch out your `string` with a `String` object." I thought you were saying that the two are different types and the compiler is just using `String` when you say `string` but I realize now (based on your comment) that is not what you meant. My apologies; your understanding is correct. It happens at compile time; that is replacing all instances of `string` with `String` in your code or vice versa will emit exactly the same IL.

Answer (score 6):

Since C# represents all primitive data types as objects, it is possible to call an object method on a primitive data type. (Source: [MSDN - Data Types - C# vs Java](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228360%28VS.80%29.aspx))

Answer (score 5):

They are aliased to their matching System Namespace types in .Net.  Here's a rundown of the alias list for value types in .Net:

- [bool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8f5xwh7.aspx) = [System.Boolean](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.aspx)
- [byte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693.aspx) = [System.Byte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.byte.aspx)
- [char](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9h8tsay.aspx) = [System.Char](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.aspx)
- [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) = [System.Decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx)
- [double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx) = [System.Double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx)
- [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx) = [System.Enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.aspx)
- [float](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx) = [System.Single](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.aspx)
- [int](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kzh1b5w(VS.71).aspx) = [System.Int32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx)
- [long](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk.aspx) = [System.Int64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.aspx)
- [sbyte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d86he86x.aspx) = [System.SByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.sbyte.aspx)
- [short](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybs77ex4.aspx) = [System.Int16](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int16.aspx)
- [uint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0sksh43.aspx) = [System.UInt32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uint32.aspx)
- [ulong](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t98873t4.aspx) = [System.UInt64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uint64.aspx)
- [ushort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cbf1574z.aspx) = [System.UInt16](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uint16.aspx)

Comment: There's no boxing/unboxing with string, it is a reference type.

Comment: @Bruno Reis:  Thanks for the catch, I often forget this, added a full reference of ones that do box/unbox in case it's helpful to someone later.

Comment: Still wrong: **boxing** is treating a value type as `Object`. As mentioned, **Int32 is the same as int**. If you "cast" an `int` to an `Int32`, there's absolutely no boxing taking place. Boxing is converting to object. Your list describes the type aliases, but it has absolutely nothing to do with boxing/unboxing. You should review these concepts.

Comment: FYI, any value type is subject to boxing/unboxing, even the "custom" ones you may define yourself. What you describe is a concept completely unrelated to boxing/unboxing.

Comment: @Bruno Reis: Thanks!, I had always though it unboxed on a (Int32)int scenario sticking it on the stack for method calls, I see with our generated IL that it doesn't...learn something every day on here.  I updated this in case someone else trips over it later. I appreciate the lesson, I'm sure it'll help in  project down the road.

Comment: @BrunoReis As well as upon casting to object, you get boxing when casting to an interface.