# How can primitive data types have functions?

Tags: c#, types

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do primitive types in C# have their own operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106132/why-do-primitive-types-in-c-sharp-have-their-own-operations)

I'm learning C# and I find following code confusing:
`int.Parse();`
How can primitive data types have functions ?

Comment: I've a question of my own: **Why won't they?**

Comment: @gdoron To my knowledge only objects and structure variables can have functions (in C++/Java).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primitive types are actually `struct` objects in C#.

In the case of the int, it is represents by a Int32 struct. You can actually see it easily by hovering the `int` word:

[image]

[Int32 structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx)

Comment: To the point answer with good reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Primitive data types are structures. A good explanation about the difference to "native" structs can be found [here](http://www.kynosarges.de/StructPerformance.html#Structs).

Comment: Thanks for the link. Very informative.

Answer (score 1):

Primitive types in .net framework are `structure`.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, types such as int are a hybrid - they're both a primitive value type containing the value, but they're also structs - System.Int32 - that contains methods, both instance methods (you can call `myInt.ToString()`, or even `5.ToString()`) and static methods (`int.Parse()`, which is shorthand for `System.Int32.Parse()`.

Comment: Not exactly, `int` is just syntax sugar for `System.Int32`, which is a `struct`, meaning it inherits from `ValueType`, which inherits from `Object`. Both `int` and `System.Int32` compile down to the same bytecode. `Parse()` and `TryParse()` are part of `Int32`, while `.ToString()` is from `Object`. The `Int32` struct holds the value.

Comment: So they are hybrid or struct only ?

Comment: When I said hybrid, I meant in the sense that they are both a primitive value type (like in C and other languages), but like in Java, where Integer is a full-fledged object, they are derived from Object and have methods. The C# implementation shares elements of both.

Answer (score -1):

As per .net specification Data types are categorized as either stack based or heap based variables. This distinction is made how and where variable will be stored. Stack based variables are stored by value.

Now concentrating on your question, how can int have functions. If you go through every integral data type such as int, short, decimal, string, double, long .. has a corresponding heap based class.

.net compiler internally converts integral types (primitive) to Heap based representation.

so int becomes Int32
   short becomes int16

and so on.

BTW, integral types, structure, enum are stack based variable which are stored directly in memory not as a reference.

Comment: There's so much wrong here that this has to be a joke, right?

Comment: Find the guy who taught you that, and beat him up! **=)**