# C# predefined types vs primitive types?

Tags: c#

I have been studying C# lately and there is a thing called "predefined type". 
I thought it is another name of the primitive type.
But my friend told me that those are quite different from each other.
Just got confused.

Are these two names for the same thing, or are they totally different?

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664635(v=vs.71).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711900(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @TimS. One of your links is for C#, the other for VB.NET.

Comment: I believe they are the same.

Comment: No, they are not. This question has been asked here before - for particular types ([String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965752/is-string-a-primitive-type)) and [in general](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106132/why-do-primitive-types-in-c-sharp-have-their-own-operations). While there's obvious room for interpretation of terminology, predefined types are built-ins and primitive are another name of value types.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503/should-i-use-int-or-int32

Answer (score 11):

In the [Type.IsPrimitive documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isprimitive.aspx) there's a complete list of primitive types:

> The primitive types are Boolean, Byte, SByte, Int16, UInt16, Int32,
>   UInt32, Int64, UInt64, IntPtr, UIntPtr, Char, Double, and Single.

And section 1.2.1 ([Predefined types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664635%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)) clearly makes the difference between these and predefined reference types:

> The predefined reference types are `object` and `string`. The type `object`
>   is the ultimate base type of all other types. The type `string` is used
>   to represent Unicode string values.

So I guess it's quite obvious they are different - at least, in .NET terminology.

Comment: One interesting point is that `decimal` is a predefined but not a primitive

Answer (score 6):

Predefined are the types that are specially supported by the compiler. They alias .NET framework types in the ***System*** namespace. They are also called built-in types.

How are they supported by the compiler? They have their own keyword. For example ***int*** keyword is used to predefine ***System.Int32*** type. This means that when you define an integer variable in C#, you can do so by typing:

`int myIntVar = 3;`

instead of

`System.Int32 myIntVar = 3;`

This is only syntatic difference though.

Primitive types are all predefined ***value*** types minus ***decimal*** type. I made a sketch that demonstrates this:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: This isn't an accurate example, for example: `int a = 10; int b = (int) -a; int c = (System.Int32) -a;` in that example `b` is fine, but `c` will output an error. Sometimes the framework type and its alias don't mean the same.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Hector. 

Your example will not work because you will need to enclose -a in parentheses. You are getting the error at compile time because as compiler says: "To cast a negative value, you must enclose the value in parentheses ".

It is still only syntactic difference as I said above. I can make your example work like so: int a = 10; int b = int.Parse((-a).ToString());           int c = System.Int32.Parse((-a).ToString()); It is still a very interesting observation though and I wonder why does compiler treat this example like that.

Comment: This article describes this situation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0075

Comment: @HéctorÁlvarez  - `(System.Int32) -a` isn't valid, but `-(System.Int32)a` is.  Both `-(int)a` and `(int)-a` are valid, though.